# How to solve merge conflict with protected branch?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have two protected branch, `integration` and `master`.
`integration` branch is checkout from master.
I have another branch `feature` which is not protected and need to merge into `integration` branch.
When i tried to merge my `feature` branch into `integration` branch i have merge conflict. I have `feature` branch rebased with `master` so I can not rebase my `feature` branch with `integration` and solve merge conflicts.
Is there any way I can solve conflict and merge `feature` branch into `integration` branch?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: you must rebase `integration` , I'm pretty sure that's the only way to solve the conflicts

Comment: You may simply have to do this on your local machine and push.

Answer (score 0):

Do `git pull origin integration` from your local machine while you are on the `feature` branch. Then solve the conflicts in your local machine and `push` the changes to `feature`. Then merge those branches. It should solve the issue.